# How to declare WindowsAzure in Ionic?

Tags: angular, azure, ionic-framework

I am working on connecting a mobile app I am making with the ionic framework and am working on connecting it to Azure right now. The azure website said to add the following lines of code to my `app.component.ts`:

```
declare var WindowsAzure: any;
var client = new 
WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net");
```

I am confused as to where in the app.component.ts to put this. Does it go in the @Component, the constructor, the platform? It also says to add this line of code to a page that will be connected to the service:

```
var client = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(appUrl);
```

I assume I would put this in the .ts file of a page that will be using the azure database. Where do I put this line of code? Wherever I put it, it gives a red underline because `WindowsAzure` is not defined. Do I have to do a "import { WindowsAzure } from ..."? Where would I be importing it from? I don't know the destination from which the variable is coming from?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is any npm dependencies you have not installed to import WindowsAzure?

Answer (score 0):

Code `declare var WindowsAzure: any;` should be added right after imports at top of app.components.
Code `var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net");` should be added inside AppComponent class function.